# Fixed Position HTML Elements' Movement Restriction

Tags: css, css-position

I have an HTML element which is set as position: fixed in the CSS. However, when the user scrolls to the top of the screen, I notice the fixed element overlaps another element.

How do I tell the browser that I want the element to stay below the other element, but otherwise ignore the scrolling like most fixed position elements do?

EDIT: Your answers are all great, but I guess I wasn't specific enough: I want the object to stop moving, rather than go behind the other element. Also, I can't use jquery; I can use Javascript, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to only start scrolling *after* you've 'passed it', use [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/#examples). Specifically [sticky elements](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/).

If you just want to to hide behind the other element, assign it a `z-index` lower than the other element. (`z-index` only obeys elements with `position: absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`.)

Answer (score 1):

Z-indexing rules still apply to fixed elements. Give it a lower z-index value to have it render behind the other element(s).